# Can not add new key value to object inside foreach loop using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to add one new key/value pair into object inside forEach loop using Node.js but as per my code its not working. I am explaining my code below.

```
user.StoreDetails.forEach(ele => {
    let findValue = resArr.find((item) => {return item.StoreCode === ele.StoreCode});
    ele.StoreName = findValue.StoreName;
    console.log('ele', ele);
})
```

Here I need to add new key/value pair `i.e-StoreName` but after finishing loop that key/value is appending to that particular object.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by _"but after finishing loop that key/value is appending to that particular object"_?

Comment: Can you post `console.log()` output?

Comment: Maybe need a conditional? `if (findValue) { ele.StoreName = findValue.StoreName; }` it's not clear exactly what you're trying to do